# Page still refreshing form_for remote true Rails 5

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

VERY new to Rails, and the issue I'm having is: I have a page that was one long column of check-boxes that I changed to a grid of icons with check-boxes and labels underneath; I'd ***like*** to swap out the icons images with another if the box is checked, but the original form my classmate stuck me with, doesn't want to play nice. I can get a link_to helper I use for testing to work, but not the form.

The relevant code:

```
#users_controller
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @peaks = Peak.all.to_a
    @idx = 0
    @rng = 10
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user
    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to user_path
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end

  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(peak_ids:[])
    end

end
```

the test partial:

```
#_testajax.html.erb
<%= image_tag("badges/snow.png", :class => "no-img-circle center-block", 
height: 50, width: 50)%>
<h1>Hi J</h1>
```

the show page:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-md-7">
    <%= @user.email %>
    <h3>You have climbed the following peaks:</h3>

    <ul>
      <% for peak in @user.peak_ids do %>
        <li><%= Peak.find(peak).name %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>

    <% total_ascent = 0 %>
    <% for peak in @user.peak_ids do %>
      <% total_ascent += Peak.find(peak).ascent %>
    <% end %>

    <h3>You have climbed a total of <%= total_ascent %> feet!</h3>

    <% total_climbed = @user.peak_ids.length %>
    <h3>You have climbed <%= (total_climbed/46.0*100).round %>% of the peaks!</h3>

    <h3>Add more climbs</h3>
<div class="container">
    <%= form_for current_user, :remote => true do |f| %>
      <!-- I kept the form_for construct, but changed the logic[here @peaks is an array!]  J. -->
        <% 5.times do %>
          <div class="row">
            <% @peaks.slice(@idx,@rng).each do |peak| %>
          <div class="col-md-1 small text-nowrap">
            <%= image_tag("badges/snow.png", :class => "no-img-circle center-block", :id => peak.id, height: 50, width: 50)%>
            <p><!-- paragraph tag needed to get the checkbox and text beneath the image N. -->
            <%= check_box_tag "user[peak_ids][]", peak.id, current_user.peaks.include?(peak) %>
            <%= peak.name %>
            </p>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <% @idx += @rng %><!-- instance variables for loop control N. -->
    <% end %>

  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
</div>
<%= link_to "Test", user_path, remote: true %>
<div id="test" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>  

  <div class="col-md-5">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <% if total_ascent > 50000 %>
     <%= image_tag 'badges/chevron-20.png', :size => "130x130" %>
      <p>50,000 ft!</p>
    <% end %>

    <% if total_climbed > 22 %>
      <%= image_tag 'badges/chevron-6.png', :size => "130x130" %>
      <p>Half way to 46!</p>
    <% end %>

    <% if @user.peak_ids.include? 1%>
      <%= image_tag 'badges/chevron-11.png', :size => "130x130" %>
      <p>Highest point in New York State!</p>
    <% end %>  

    <% if total_climbed == 46 %>
      <%= image_tag 'badges/002-crown.png', :size => "130x130" %>
      <p>You've climbed all 46 peaks!</p>
    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

the show.js.erb file:

```
$('#test').html("<%= j (render 'testajax') %>"); <!-- works -->
$('#test').slideDown(350); <!-- works -->
$('edit_user_1').html('<%= j (render "testajax") %>') <!-- not working -->

$('#46').attr( "src" , "<%= image_path "badges/chevron-10.png", :id => "46" %>" ); <!-- works -->
```

and snippets of the generated HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<form class="edit_user" id="edit_user_1" action="/users/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" />

      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-1 small text-nowrap">
            <img class="no-img-circle center-block" id="1" height="50" width="50" src="/assets/badges/snow-722513de9cdd817c26362e051cf1c9111e32888cc6be5b89b99855bbb46f3c88.png" alt="Snow" />
            <p><!-- paragraph tag needed to get the checkbox and text beneath the image N. -->
            <input type="checkbox" name="user[peak_ids][]" id="user_peak_ids_" value="1" checked="checked" />
            Mt. Marcy
            </p>
          </div>
    .
    .
    .
          <div class="col-md-1 small text-nowrap">
            <img class="no-img-circle center-block" id="46" height="50" width="50" src="/assets/badges/snow-722513de9cdd817c26362e051cf1c9111e32888cc6be5b89b99855bbb46f3c88.png" alt="Snow" />
            <p><!-- paragraph tag needed to get the checkbox and text beneath the image N. -->
            <input type="checkbox" name="user[peak_ids][]" id="user_peak_ids_" value="46" />
            Couchsachraga Peak
            </p>
          </div>
      </div>


  <p><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Update User" data-disable-with="Update User" /></p>
</form></div>
<a data-remote="true" href="/users/1">Test</a>
<div id="test" style="display:none;"></div>
  </div>
```

I've tried many solutions over the last 24 hours, but nothing seems to work, and most of the howto's are dated. I don't ask for help very often, but this has me stumped.

**EDIT**

Like stated previously, the controller *appears* to work for the link_to, but the page is still refreshing when I submit the form,. Thanks.

**ANSWER**

Thanks to Simple Lime, I was finally able to get this working, after initially misreading it, the following should go in the ***update*** action :

```
  def update
    @user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to user_path }
        format.js { render action: :show, format: :js } #has to go here beause of .update()
      else
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('edit_user_1').html('<%= j (render "testajax") %>') <!-- not working -->
```

On that line, you missed your octothorpe, so you're using jQuery to select an element with the tag name 'edit_user_1' (similar to selecting all paragraph tags on a page by doing `$('p')`.

```
$('#edit_user_1').html('<%= j (render "testajax") %>') <!-- should work -->
```

unless I'm missing something in the question that appears to be the only thing not working for you?

NOTE: this will only work for that one user, using `$("#edit_user_#{@user.id}")` should make it work for all users, you could also do something like `$('form.edit_user')` if there's only the one on the page. You'll run into similar issues with `$('#46')` if `peak.id` will ever change (looks like it does), you'll probably need to figure out some other way to target that image.

For the overarching problem of the `link_to` working but not the `form_for`, `form_for` is submitting to the `update` action in the controller which just says to `redirect_to user_path` (which I was unaware you could do without passing it a user object, but it's apparently working for your `link_to`). You need to add a respond_to block and render the show.js.erb inside of it for the js requests. The following is untested but shows the general idea.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to user_path }
  format.js { render action: :show, format: :js }
end
```

Comment: +1 for the use of octothorpe ;) But that's not the issue here, I get no response from Ajax in the form_for, period. The link_to helper does kinda work, but somehow I know I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. J.

Comment: @Joliet updated my answer, somehow missed all that in the question.

Comment: Sorry I marked your answer so late, I've been busy trying to complete the app, but that's no excuse for bad manners. Thanks for all your help, I've learned a lot about the how Rails actually works. Take care. J.